# Add 5 days to datestring

Tags: javascript

I have today's date like so:

```
var date = new Date();

var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
var mm = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
var dd = date.getDate().toString();

var mmChars = mm.split('');
var ddChars = dd.split('');

var datestring = yyyy + '-' + (mmChars[1] ? mm : "0" + mmChars[0]) + '-' + (ddChars[1] ? dd : "0" + ddChars[0]);
```

Now what I am trying to do is add 5 days to the `datestring` date, how would I do this?

My issue with this is, I have the date already formatted to my liking, I want to add 5 days to the already formatted date.

Comment: this is a javascript question and not a jquery question.

Comment: @Stryner your correct, thanks!

Comment: duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime

Answer (score 1):

You could add 5 days to the original date object you have. See [Date.getDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate).

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 5);
```

Comment: my issue with this is, I have the date already formatted to my liking, I want to add 5 days to the already formatted date.

Comment: @user979331 It would be a good idea to make a function to accept a date and return a formatted string. Then you would be able to perform operations on the original date object and serialize it to string whenever you want.

Comment: @user979331 Parse it back into a date and do what Billy suggests